# Locate all non-number elements in a pandas.Series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, text-processing

For a pd.Series with mixed strings and numbers (integers and floats), I need to identify all non-number elements. For example

`data = pd.Series(['1','wrong value','2.5','-3000','>=50','not applicable', '<40.5'])`

I want it to return the following elements:

```
wrong value
>=50
not applicable
<40.5
```

What I'm currently doing is:

```
data[~data.str.replace(r'[\.\-]','').str.isnumeric()]
```

That is, because `.str.isnumeric()` will give `False` to decimal points and negative signs, I had to mask "." and "-" first and then find out the non-numeric fields.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or is there any potential problem/warning with my current method? Thanks!!

Comment: What makes a string a valid number?

Comment: Was trying to get integers and floats as numbers. All other characters will render the whole string invalid.

Comment: _Was trying to get integers and floats as numbers._ How are you defining _integer_ and _float_ ?

Comment: in my example above, i was defining 1, 2.5, -3000 as integer/float. all others are invalid values per this definition.

Comment: _all others are invalid values per this definition._ What definition? `1`, `2.5` and `-3000` are examples, not a definition. In any case, I saw that `pandas.to_numeric` does the trick for you.

Comment: Yes. That works for me. `errors='coerce'` helps with flagging all the invalid values `np.nan`, exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to flag them

```
data[pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce').isna()]

Out[1159]:
1       wrong value
4              >=50
5    not applicable
6             <40.5
dtype: object
```